# Multiplies I / O reading with interruption in stm32f767zi

Tags: stm32, interrupts, io, gpio-external-interrupt

I am developing a board where 40 low I / O ports will be read, and I would like when I detect a low border to activate interruption for reading the port. in the documentation it says that **"Up to 168 GPIOs can be connected to the 16 external interruption lines"** connection is internal by software or external with components.

If it is externally I thought of a circuit like this.

[image]

Each input will have a resistor and two diodes, a resistor to limit the output current to not saturate the input port, D3 positive input protection diode, D4 diode to protect the action of another port connected to the same interruption port.

If I can read the 40 internal ports, disregard this circuit.
The "INx" signals for reading the 40 ports have an average of 10ms to 300 ms from each port and are random for each port and do not have a sequence.

My doubt is:

Can I read 40 internal ports with an interrupt?

If not, is the circuit I set up a good alternative internally?

Will the reading of the 40 ports have a loss for being between 10ms-300ms intervals for each port?

Answer (score 0):

No, since like you quoted, from the 168 possible interrupt pin sources, only 16 pins can be selected at once. And for each bit, like pin0, you can select the port only. So you can't have both PA0 and PB0 as interrupt sources, but can have PA0 and PA1, or PA0 and PB1 etc. If you wire those externally together, if one pin is already interrupting, you don't get another interrupt if another pin goes active. What you could do is set up a timer interrupt every 10ms and read all IO pins and check if there are changes that need some action.

Comment: I can connect 10 inputs on each interrupt pin and create a reading condition when the interrupt is active for the 10 pins, so it wouldn't depend on a team. it would use 4 interrupts for the 40 pins and each generated interrupt would read 10 inputs. would be better ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. But no matter if you divide it into four groups of 10 pins, if one pin on a group is active and stays active, it will not generate a new interrupt it a new pin in same group goes active. What is it that you are trying to do even?

Comment: Each group of 10 pins will be connected on the same interruption line externally as the one in the image that I put, when the interruption is active by any of the 10 pins when treating the interruption, there will be a read_gpio while for the 10 pins of the group. then if another pin of the same group activates also the while will process.

Comment: It still makes no sense, at least to me. If you know you need to poll for changes because one interrupt is already active so new ones can't happen, why even bother with interrupts? How fast you will need to respond to the pins? What generates the interrupt and what must be done when it happens?

Comment: I thought about the interruption because the software is already processing other data from another interruption. Do I have a CAN with interruption in case the team does not use readings of the inputs? well each pin that is active will be processed the time of the last time that it was active and will pass 4 values of 32 bits for some of the buffer variables of each one.